# On scroll, scroll 100vh down/up works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to handle scroll as when I scroll down I want to scroll full `viewport.height` and up same but opposite way:

It is working with this but it work only for once for scrolling down and once back up (Also it has some time while I cannot scroll and if I go down and up after some time ig goes down and wait and again up):

```js
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
var height = viewport().height;
$(document).on('wheel', function(e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
    if(delta > 0) $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: height+'px'});
    else $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '-'+height+'px'});
    return false;
  });
```

```css
body{min-height: 300vh; overflow: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you need to increment or decrement the `scrollTop` from its current position. Your current code only sets it to a single value repeatedly, hence nothing appears to change.

To fix this, prepend the `scrollTop` value with `+=` or `-=` depending on the required direction of travel. Also note that you can simply us `$(window).height()` in jQuery in place of the `viewport()` function you currently have.

Finally you also need to include a `stop(true)` call in there to prevent animations being queued up when a user repeatedly scrolls the mousewheel.

```js
$(document).on('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
    scrollTop: (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ? '+=' : '-=') + $(window).height() + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 300vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```